# Filter child property collections of an entity using breezejs

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have a use case where I use the child property collections of an entity and filter it to show in a table.

I am aware of the “any” and “all” query operators but as far as I can tell it does not filter the actual child property collections on the entity.

So basically when I do a query like this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Farms")
    .where("FarmYields", "any", "year",  "==", 2010);
```

Then the result has only the Farms of which the FarmYields has a year of 2010 as expected. But the FarmYields collection on each Farm entity still has all the FarmYields regardless of the year.

To get my results to only show the FarmYields that I am interested in I thought of filtering the child collection, but modifying the FarmYields seems like a wrong move because its a Nonscalar navigation property.

I guess my question is how can I filter the child property collection of an entity, or perhaps I am on a totally wrong path here. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want to do if you start your query from FarmYields instead. Something like,

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('FarmYields')
            .where('year', '==', 2010)
            .expand('Farm');

 mgr.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (data) {
        var underscore = _;
        var farms = underscore.pluck(data.results, 'Farm');
     });
```

Now your Farms collection will only have FarmYields where 'year' equals 2010

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I want to show all the Farms in a table and colour the ones that has records for 2010 on the FarmYields child collection. I have resorted to just checking if any of the Farm entity child FarmYields has data for 2010, but was wondering if I could just get those in the child collection because there is data from the year 2000 to 2014.

Comment: I see. If that's the case, the only thing I can think of is doing the query in 2 steps. First is to query for Farms that has at least 1 FarmYields with year 2010 (which is what you're already doing). And second is to query all Farms which don't have any FarmYields with year 2010. The combination of these results should give you all Farms collection.